# unable to set multiple milestone on github, is there any other solutions?

Tags: github, github-actions, jira, milestone

What if the issue is a bug that appears in two separate versions that have different release cycles, e.g. major v1 gets monthly maintenance releases, but major v2 won’t ship for another quarter? Do you create a different, duplicate issues that have v1 milestone and a v2 milestones respectively? How do you sync those issues?

And https://github.com/OasisLMF/OasisLMF/issues/969 , seems it is unable to set multiple milestone to manage such problem?

Jira like tools can manage such problems, but I'm wondering if is there any other solutions on github? i mean if github actions, or other solutions?

Comment: The best alternative I could think of would be to simply use labels. You can create a label for each version and attach it to the issues. In the view, you can also display only open issues with a certain label.
Would that be an acceptable solution?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the query- With versions do you mean different Github Instances or Projects?
Anyway, in both cases, you can sync issues from two versions including all the fields, bi-directionally with Exalate.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).